# How much delta V did the V2 have?

Tags: delta-v, karman-line, v2

The V2 rocket was the first to cross the Karman line. To pass it you need at least 1.4 km\s. How much delta V did the V2 rocket have?

Comment: Delta V depends on payload. How much payload do you think of?

Comment: You won't reach the Karman line with 1.4 km/s of velocity. You can't ignore air resistance when throwing objects at supersonic speeds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am finding significantly different specifications for the V2 from different sources ([Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/v/v-2.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2_rocket)) -- probably because they weren't all built the same -- but assuming a gross liftoff mass of 12805 kg, mass at burnout of 4008 kg, and sea-level specific impulse of 203 seconds, the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation)

$$\Delta v = v_\text{e} \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f} = I_\text{sp} g_0 \ln \frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

tells us that the delta-V would be around 2300 m/s. The specific impulse would increase with altitude to a maximum of 239 seconds in vacuum, so the delivered delta-V might be closer to 2500 m/s.